# There are twenty different books which will be put on three different shelves. There is no restriction of the number of books in each shelf.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to arrange the books?

I tried to compute by using combination with repetitions that is the 3C22 but I am not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

If the books are *distinguishable* (and you should expect that from books) then see the answer of Nemo.

If not then this can be solved with [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). You are actually looking for the number of ways number $20$ can be written as a sum of $3$ nonnegative integers and the answer is: $$\binom{22}{2}$$ Choosing $2$ spots out of $20+2=22$ to contain a bar corresponds with discerning $3$ shelves.

Comment: what about if we give an additional condition that is each shelf should not be empty?

Comment: Then you start by placing a book at each shelf. $17$ books are left and now number $17$ must be split up in $3$ nonnegative integers. This results in $\binom{19}{2}$ possibilities.

Comment: what about if the 20 books are all different? does it give the same answer?

Comment: See the answer by nemo for the case that the books are all different.

Answer (score 1):

We have to count the linear arrangements of the set
$$\{1,2,\ldots,20, S_1,S_2,S_3\}$$
fulfilling the extra conditions that $S_1$ comes before $S_2$, and $S_3$ comes last. There are
$${22!\over2}=562\,000\,363\,888\,803\,840\,000$$
such arrangements.

Comment: why is it divided by 2?

Comment: @JLee: It's a way to handle the fact that the two planks $S_1$ and $S_2$ look alike.

Comment: I see now. Thx. Are you "Nemo" that they refer to in the other answer?

Comment: @JLee The answer of Nemo was deleted before this answer was given. He came to a total of $3^{20}$ (for each of the $20$ books $3$ choices).

Comment: Recap: If the books are indistinguishable, then $$\binom{22}{2}$$ If the books are distinguishable but the order on the shelf doesn't matter, then $3^{20}$. If the books are distinguishable and the order on the shelf matters, then $${22!\over2}=562\,000\,363\,888\,803\,840\,000$$